# Ruby setter doesn't work with eval

Tags: ruby, eval, setter

I use `eval()` in an `initialize` method:

```
class ActiveRecord::FakedModel

  def initialize(attributes={})
    attributes = {} if not attributes

    attributes.each do |attr_name, value|
      eval("@#{attr_name}=#{value.inspect}")
    end

    @attributes = attributes
  end
...
end
```

and have a setter for cleaning whitespaces:

```
class ContactForm < ActiveRecord::FakedModel
  attr_accessor :plz

  def plz=(plz)
    @plz = plz.try(:delete,' ')
  end
...
end
```

but this setter doesn't work when I give 'plz' in a hash:

```
c=ContactForm.new(:plz=>' 1  3 3 3 ')
=> #<ContactForm:0x1024e3a10 @attributes={:plz=>" 1  3 3 3 "}, @plz=" 1  3 3 3 ">
```

Is there anything wrong with using setters in `eval`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your eval statement is not calling the setter method, it is setting the instance variable directly. If you want your constructor to use the setter, use [send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
attributes.each do |attr_name, value|
  send "#{attr_name}=", value
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  [Object#instance_variable_set](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set) method for setting instance variables.

```
attributes.each do |attr_name, value|
  self.instance_variable_set("@#{attr_name}", value.inspect)
end
```

Comment: This is a good tip, but not really an answer to the problem, which was the setter not being called.

Answer (score 1):

To execute a method dynamically, use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send).

```
class ActiveRecord::FakedModel

  def initialize(attributes={})
    attributes = {} if not attributes

    attributes.each do |attr_name, value|
      send("#{attr_name}=", value)
    end

    @attributes = attributes
  end

end
```

You also get the advantage you don't need to call inspect and force a cast to String of the variable.

You can also use [`Object#instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set), but in this case you are bypassing the setter method and if you have some custom logic in the setter, such as casting, the code won't work as expected.

```
class ActiveRecord::FakedModel

  def initialize(attributes={})
    attributes = {} if not attributes

    attributes.each do |attr_name, value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr_name}", value)
    end

    @attributes = attributes
  end

end
```